# Wordpress URLs - auto adding -2/-3

Tags: php, wordpress, url

Having a bit of an issue with wordpress URLs, it seems to automatically add -3 to the end of my urls making them look very messy, there isn't a page named the same so I'm unsure why it's adding these on? Any ideas how to fix this? When i goto the url without the -3 it automatically diverts to the -3 version, all very strange and can't find anyone with the same issue…

Comment: [A brief Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+append+number+to+url) yields at least 2 results on WP support of people complaining about exactly this, with solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be something to do with the url rewriting section, im not familiar with wordpress as I use Joomla, but it has a similar feature to rewrite SEO friendly urls. In the admin back end there should be an url rewrite / SEO friendly urls section, take a look in there, to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Iain, seems I had to navigation to the trash and empty trash as there were old posts with the same names!